# Ubuntu 20.04 : Fingerprint authentication not available for all users [using fprintd somerville-millesa]

Tags: 20.04, login, dell, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I am using Dell Latitude 7520 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed. I have enrolled my fingerprint via terminal using fprintd-enroll and have successfully enrolled my print. I am able to login to my machine using my fingerprint.

But I am not able to use this for SUDO operation. Also, during the first login, it always says "Login Keyring was not unlocked" and I anyway have to type my password for logging in the first time after restart.

One thing to note is, I have 2 accounts on my machine. One is the IT Domain Admin account and my domain account. When I logged in to the IT Admin account, the Fingerprint option was available in Settings -> Users -> Authentication. But the same was not available for my account both in my login as well as IT Admin's login. Both accounts are Administrator accounts.

I am using somerville-mellisa and installed the fprintd using the steps available here https://github.com/dsd/fprintd/issues/3#issuecomment-962422370

What I want to achieve is to use SUDO commands with fingerprint and a way to add fingerprint option in the settings without using fingerprint-gui package as I do not want to mess up the libraries on my work machine. Also, I want to understand why the fingerprint option is available only for the IT Admin account and not my account. Because If I could add my fingerprint option via the settings, I hope the print might work for sudo as well.

fprintd version : 1.90.9-1~ubuntu20.04.1
note : fingerprint option is enabled in pam-auth-update menu.

Please forgive me if I'm not clear and please do add a comment so that I can add more necessary details.